# Project Euler - Problem 22: Answer off by 3.35 percent

Tags: c

I tried to solve [Problem 22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22) of Project Euler, by first sorting the names using a bubble sort implementation, and then adding the name scores all together using a FOR loops. The "COLIN" example works fine, and some other random scores work fine as well. But, the overall sum is wrong.

I have searched similar problem 22 questions on StackOverFlow and similar coding Q/A sites, however, it seems like most people are using python, R, or C#. I can solve this problem in python by using libraries, but I wanted to learn so I tried to do it in C but it is failing. P.S. I am relatively new to programming, but I doubt that my poorly implemented bubble sort is causing the problem. The issue is: I have tried putting 'printf' statements in a lot of places, but still cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

```c
    FILE *file;
    char list[46448];

    file = fopen("/home/USER_NAME/Downloads/p022_names.txt", "r");
    fscanf(file, "%s", list);

    char *tok = strtok(list, ",");
    char *token[5163];
    token[0] = tok;
    int i = 1;
    char *temp;

    while (tok != NULL){
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
        token[i] = tok;
        i++;
    }

    for(int j = 5162; j >= 0; j--){ 
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            if(strcmp(token[i], token[i + 1]) > 0){
                temp = token[i];
                token[i] = token[i + 1];
                token[i + 1] = temp;
            }   
        }
    }

    char str[20];
    int sum;
    int score = 0;

    for(int z = 0; z < 5163; z++){
        sum = 0;
        strcpy(str, token[z]);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            if((str[i] != '\"') & (str[i] != 0)){
                sum += str[i] - 64;
            }
        }
        score += (sum * (z + 1));
        }
    printf("Names Score: %d\n", score);
}
```

However, I am constantly getting a wrong answer of 900429178. The correct answer is 871198282.

Comment: Is `if((str[i] != 34)` supposed to skip spaces? You might want to check that magic number. You didn't link to or explain the question, so just guessing.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. That is to skip quotation marks --> " <-- with an ASCII value of 34 in base 10.  I created a: char *token[5163] to store all the names stripped by strtok() function using delimiter: comma --> , <-- so the quotation marks remain a part of the names. And I also skip over 0's in the str[20] because it is an array with sizeof str = 20, so after performing: str[20] = token[i], the remaining places are filled with zeroes.

Comment: Why do you have to write the encoding values? Character literals and escape sequences exist for a reason: `'\"'`

Comment: Is using ASCII encoding value causing any problem in the functionality of the code? If so, I will remove it. But, I am just used to it.

Comment: It's bad practice because it makes your code hard to read and prone to bugs, especially since you're asking a question here and you want people to be able to read and understand your code easily. It may not be the problem here, but it's a good idea to get in the habit of using character literals. Also, the C++ standard doesn't guarantee ASCII is used. Why make all that effort to memorize the ASCII table just to write less readable and potentially buggy code?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I never took any classes of computer science, but I was always interested in coding. So, what I learn is just from online courses and a few books that I am reading. And I edited the code:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop `for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)` fails to stop when an entry ends. Just before this loop, `token[z]` is copied into `str`. This copy stops at the null byte that terminates `token[z]`. Beyond that, it leaves in `str` whatever was there from before.

Then the loop `for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)` adds values for **all** letter non-quote and non-null characters in `str`, including letters that are left over from prior long names.

This loop should be modified to stop where the current name ends.

Comment: @Yahya: That should be `memset(str, 0, sizeof str);`.